# An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to ''. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol

Tags: wcf

I am getting the below error while trying to call an external service from my service which was hosted in IIS .

Error : **An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to ''. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.**

And I am not getting any error while trying to call the same external service from a console application.

Any suggestions will help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several reasons you can get this error.  Without seeing your client and service configs and how you are calling the service, it's difficult to give you a more precise answer.

Comment: Issue is with the firewall. Firewall restricting to call the service out side of the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the firewall. When i try to call the external service from console application, the service call going through without any errors, as there was no IIS involved in calling the service. But when i call the external service from another service hosted in IIS, firewall comes to the picture.